# Sign-Out Any Other Devise User Types On Sign-In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have three Devise User types: Admin, User and Subscriber. I would like to ensure that if a User signs in (or registers), any current_admin or current_subscriber is signed out, and likewise for each of the other user types, so essentially only a single user type can be signed in at one time.

It doesn't seem that Devise handles this out of the box. Handling this in a subclassed sessions controller doesn't seem like the correct approach as this would not work in cases where a user was signed in after registration.

It appears that `Devise:DatabaseAuthenticatable::after_database_authentication` [might be appropriate](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#after_database_authentication-instance_method). But this means exposing Devise ..._signed_in? to each user type model. And this doesn't really belong in a model anyway.

```
  # Post authentication hook
  def after_database_authentication
    sign_out current_user if user_signed_in?
    sign_out current_subscriber if subscriber_signed_in?
  end
```

However placing the logic in a subclass of the `Devise::SessionsController` isn't much good as this will never get run during/after registration.

**How should I handle this?**